# Network applet missing from notification area after upgrading to Ubuntu MATE 15.04

Tags: 15.04, mate

I just upgraded from Ubuntu MATE 14.10 to 15.04. After the upgrade, the network manager icon, which I had in the notification area until then, was gone. How can I restore it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The applet which manages this icon is called `nm-applet`.

In my case, I had an autostart entry for it in `~/.config/autostart/nm-applet.desktop`, which I had created on Ubuntu MATE 14.10. (If you don't, copy `nm-applet.desktop` over from `/etc/xdg/autostart/`.)

After commenting out the following two lines:

```
#AutostartCondition=GNOME3 unless-session gnome
#Hidden=true
```

and logging out and back in, the applet was there again.

Note: if you use other desktop environments aside from MATE, you may need to re-enable `AutostartCondition` and tweak it according to your needs.

Note 2: this no longer seems to work on 18.04.